# Google App Engine go deployment failed: golang.org/x/net/http2/client_conn_pool.go:302:6: undefined: errors.Is

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Here's the error message after I ran `gcloud app deploy`:

```
Step #0: # golang.org/x/net/http2
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/client_conn_pool.go:302:6: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/server.go:240:72: undefined: tls.VersionTLS13
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:417:30: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:417:45: undefined: os.ErrDeadlineExceeded
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:2076:5: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:2080:5: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:2084:5: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: # google.golang.org/grpc/credentials
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/tls.go:233:2: undefined: tls.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/tls.go:234:2: undefined: tls.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/tls.go:235:2: undefined: tls.TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
Step #0: # google.golang.org/grpc/status
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/status/status.go:128:5: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/status/status.go:131:5: undefined: errors.Is
Step #0: # github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/error_handler.go:36:7: undefined: "github.com/pkg/errors".Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/error_handler.go:39:7: undefined: "github.com/pkg/errors".Is
Step #0: ../_gopath/src/github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/middleware.go:89:8: r.Clone undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Clone)
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:408a098788ef4cdeec452821946b986ef82ce5ebceecbdf748ffecf329765bce" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
```

I'm quite sure I installed all the dependencies the code needed on the Google Cloud Shell. And the project runs fine locally.

I searched in the `$GOPATH/golang.org/x/net/http2/client_conn_pool.go`, and `errors` was corrected imported.

How to fix this issue?

Version info:

go: 1.17.2

Comment: The Go version in your "Goggle app engine" is definitely not 1.17.2.